# The method collectFrom(List<Integer>) is undefined for the type Main

Tags: java, list, generics, interface, compiler-errors

I have an issue with this code. It throws a "The method collectFrom(List < Integer> ) is undefined for the type Main" error, and I don't really know where's the problem.

The selector from "test1" method should choose from the list numbers lesser than 10, and mapper should increase those chosen numbers by 10.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public Main() {
    List<Integer> src1 = Arrays.asList(1, 7, 9, 11, 12);
    System.out.println(test1(src1));
  }

  public List<Integer> test1(List<Integer> src) {
    Selector<Integer> sel = new Selector<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean select(Integer a) {
            if(a < 10) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    Mapper<Integer> map = new Mapper<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer map(Integer a) {
            return a+=10;
        }
    };
    return collectFrom(src).when(sel).mapEvery(map);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
  }
}
```

And this is my class ListCreator:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListCreator <T>{

    List<T> lista;

    private ListCreator(List<T> src) {
        this.lista = src;
    }

    public static <T> ListCreator<T> collectFrom(List<T> src) {
        ListCreator<T> ls = new ListCreator<T>(src);
        return ls;
    };

    public ListCreator<T> when(Selector s) {
        List<T> whenLista = new ArrayList<T>();
        for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); ++i) {
                if(s.select(lista.get(i))) {
                    whenLista.add(lista.get(i));
                }
            }
        this.lista = whenLista;
        return this;
    };

    public List<Integer> mapEvery (Mapper m) {
        List<Integer> mapLista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); ++i) {
            mapLista.add((Integer)m.map(lista.get(i)));
        }
        return mapLista;
    }


}
```

Selector and Mapper are just simple, parameterized interfaces.

Comment: `collectFrom` is a method of `ListCreator`, not `Main`.

Answer (score 0):

`collectFrom is a static method defined in the`ListCreator`class, not in`Main`. You could qualify the call:

```
return ListCreator.collectFrom(src).when(sel).mapEvery(map);
```

Or just statically import it:

```
import static mypackage.ListCreator.collectFrom;
```